# Android Studio shows Build Tools 21.1 not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Android Studio shows Build Tools 21.1 not installed even if I can see it completely installed in sdk directory (My sdk directory is "C:/Program Files/Android/sdk")(I can see Build Tools files in /sdk/build-tools/21.1.x)(It didn;t bnot work when it was installed in default directory too). Note that I had downloaded Android Studio 1.0 completely from Google Website itself and successfully installed it. I have not been able to start it even once since then as it starts downloading Build Tools 21.1 automatically even if I already have it. I dont have enough internet to download it again. Even the download won't cancel and I have to forcibly close it. If i try to start Studio when not connected to internet, it shows Build Tools was not installed and after clicking finish, sometimes it starts sometimes not.

Please help me. I have tried other options told by users over the internet but none could help me!

Comment: there may be some part not present in your sdk so android studio downloads it without downloading it android studio is not going to start

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar But twice it has started. First time the Android Studio new app pop up was shown but was not functional. Second time I was able to create a new project but I didn't go far than the screen asking app name and package name. I had closed the UI then. Why is its behavior so much unpredictable?

Comment: some time android studio is stubborn, we have to deal with it just do as it say

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar When I ran this command (android list sdk -a) in cmd, I could see Build Tools 21.1.2 listed there.

Comment: it must be listed but there must be some part of the api missing so the android studio needs to download it

Comment: Or perhaps you actually have two distinct installations - one where you have the build tools installed, and another one in a different place which Android Studio is trying to add the build tools to.